# How does the compiler know which type to return

Tags: c++, c++14, auto, type-deduction

[This article](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/the-c14-standard-what-you-need-to-know/240169034) says:

> If I write a line of code like this inside a function: `return 1.4`, It is obvious to both me and the compiler that the function is returning a **double**.

It is not obvious to me: the return type could be a float, a double, or a long double. How does the compiler choose between the 3 types?

Comment: As described [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal) `no suffix` is `double`, `f` or `F` is `float`, `l` or `L` is `long double`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `1.4` is a `double`. `float` is written as `1.4f`

```
75         // int
75u        // unsigned int
75l        // long
75ul       // unsigned long 
75lu       // unsigned long

3.14159L   // long double
6.02e23f   // float
```

[Source](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/constants/)

Comment: Sorry to be nitpicky: `Double` and `Float` are no standard types but `double` and `float` are. C++ is case-sensitive.

Comment: @cad in the first I wrote float with capital because it is the start of a sentence then I make it inside a code quota then I unconsciously convert double to Double to be same as Float :D .. Thanks for notifying ;)

Answer (score 3):

`1.4` is a `double` literal as opposed to the `float` literal `1.4f` and the `long double` literal `1.4l`.

Therefore, the compiler can deduce the type unambiguously.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are asking about `auto` return type deduction, otherwise the return type is whatever you declare it to be.

The answer is straight forward: The literal `1.4` has type `double`, not `float` or `long double`, so `double` will be deduced. Easy as that.

Answer (score 1):

Because 1.4 (or any other floating point number) is `double`. To make it `float` you need to write `1.4f`, and `long double` is `1.4L`.

Answer (score 1):

1.4 is **double** here, any simple decimal point number is **double**.

**float** will be 1.4f

**long double** will be 1.4L

```
1.4  // double
1.4f // float
1.4L // long double
```